# Insert file into SQL Server 2008 R2 using Bulk Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert a file of 500 MB into table (column data type : `VARBINARY(MAX)`) using Bulk method, the SQL takes about 15 min to insert the file. I have 2GB RAM and my PC is core 2 duo and I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

My questions:

- Is it normal to take 15 min ! , or it's too long?
- Are there any faster methods?

Thanks.

My procedure is SQL is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UploadFile]
(
    @FileName   nvarchar(100) , 
    @FileSize  nvarchar(50) ,
    @FileDescription  nvarchar(200),
    @FileExtontion  nvarchar(10), 
    @DateUploaded  nvarchar(50),
    @FilePath  nvarchar(3500),
    @UserId int 
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @FileInBinary varbinary(MAX)

    IF OBJECT_ID('#ORStable') IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        -- Temporary stored into a hash table for avoid data error     
        CREATE TABLE #ORStable (Length BIGINT, vDocument VARBINARY(MAX))

        DECLARE @SQL_QUERY NVARCHAR(4000)
        SET @SQL_QUERY= 'INSERT INTO #ORStable
                         SELECT len(bulkcolumn), *
                         FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@FilePath+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BinaryData'

        exec SP_executesql @SQL_QUERY
    END

    SELECT TOP 1 @FileInBinary = vDocument FROM #ORStable

    insert into [File] ([FileName], FileSize, FileDescription, FileExtontion,
                        DateUploaded, FileInBinary, UserId)
    values (@FileName, @FileSize, @FileDescription, @FileExtontion,
            @DateUploaded, @FileInBinary, @UserId)

    DROP TABLE dbo.#ORStable
END
```

Comment: This is not a programming question, you should move this question to [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Well - show us **your code!** What is your SQL statement? What is the structure of the table you're inserting into?

Comment: This is indeed very slow even considering that multiple copies of this data are being made. Maybe the system starts paging because of those copies. Find the delta of hard page faults while this is running. Use Process Explorer, use the system memory information "Window".

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to insert a file of 500 MB into table (column data type : VARBINARY(MAX)) using Bulk 
>   method,

Large file for a low performance system like you have.

> Is it normal to take 15 min ! , or it's too long?

How long would it take to copy that file between folders, twice at the same time? (which is a little more than SQL Server needs to do due to logging)? Expect that to either fly - my sql databases can copy stuff like that with nearly 1gb / second - or crawl (likely on a low power machine that likely has a single slow disc and not a ton of SSDs).

> Are there any faster methods?

Get proper hardware for the task at hand. IO is king - and SQL Server lives by it. Your machien is RAM starved for this job and likely has a similar non-requirements-matching disc subsystem.

Comment: My system take 1 min to copy a file 500 MB from Folder to another

Comment: But SQL needs to keep a lot more in memory - and seriously 2gb is not enough to even have a decent experience windows level wise (my tablet says) so you add the paging to that. Death by not knowing computer basics, I would say. Anda file cope - ONE file copy - is 2 streams of operations. A sql insert is a minimum of 3 streams.